# Android - Different Status Bar issues when changing fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, statusbar

I am facing a rather annoying issue on Android.

I have an activity which has 3 fragments inside, all fragments fill the screen. The designer was very specific about the look of the statusbar on the devices and this is what he requested:

- First Fragment: Transparent Status Bar with White Text and a background image that also falls behind the status bar.
- Second Fragment: Transparent Status Bar with Dark Text and a background image that also falls behind the status bar.
- Third Fragment: Status Bar with Custom Color and Dark Text that doesn't let content get beneath it.

How on earth do I do this, considering that they all must be fragments in a single activity and I've played with flags like  `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS`, `windowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS`, `decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR`, `decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN`, `decorView.systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE`

but no combination results in a good behavior. Literally I can't get it to have the requested look. Sometimes, one fragment has a good status bar, but if I go back, the status bar stops working properly on the previous fragment and so on.

Can somebody please teach me how can I achieve this.

P.S. I can't believe Android is such a damn disappointing mess of an operating system sometimes. Handling the look of the status bar should have been an one-liner, easy to use, just like on iOS....

Answer (score 0):

Just use it in every fragment

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(Color.BLUE);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it in that way:

```
window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.white)
```

remember that you have to change the color of icons at status bar also ; )

```
window.decorView.windowInsetsController?.setSystemBarsAppearance(APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS, APPEARANCE_LIGHT_STATUS_BARS)
```

I'm using navigation component and at Activity I've got a navigation change listener who provide me current fragment's id.